# Skrollr fading text won't work but all other skrollr elements work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

Having some issues with using skrollr on some elements on my website. It works for backgrounds but I am trying to fade in and out a div with text and it won't work... I must be doing something wrong so I have created a jsfiddle to show the issue. Hopefully someone has an idea of what I am doing wrong.

HTML CODE

```
<div class="container" id="test">
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="info">
  <div class="section-wrapper">
    <div class="row section" data-center="background-position: 0 50%;" data-bottom-top="background-position: 0px 40%;" data-anchor-target="#info">
      <div id="info-wrapper" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-5" data-center="opacity: 1" data-bottom-top="opacity: 1;" data-anchor-target="info-wrapper">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>This text isn't fading in or out... What is wrong?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}

.navbar {
opacity:0.9;
filter:alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

#top-nav .active {
border-bottom: 3px #643b8d solid;
}

.section {
/*margin-top: -50px;*/
padding-top: 50px;
margin: 10px 0;
}

#test .section {
background:url(http://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect/img/bcg_slide-5.jpg) no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
height: 750px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}

#info .section {
background:url(http://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect/img/bcg_slide-5b.jpg) no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
height: 750px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}

#info-wrapper {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
opacity: 0;
}
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ak7Bg/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> uncaught exception: Unable to find anchor target "info-wrapper"

It's `data-anchor-target="#info-wrapper"` not `data-anchor-target="info-wrapper"`. Apart from that, both keyframes define `opacity:1`.

Corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/ak7Bg/1/

Comment: Hey @Prinzhorn I made the changes to my website and it worked! However, on a refresh it didn't... If I run skrollr.init().refresh() on the console I can get it to work again... so something else seems to be the issue. Do you have any ideas? I have placed the init code at the bottom and my other skrollr elements work with no issues except for this particular one with fading text...

Comment: Call init/refresh after all images have been loaded.

Comment: I have placed the init at the very bottom before </body> tag. The element that isn't working is the text itself but the background images work... there is something I am not getting. Also, I thought the init refreshes without calling refresh.

Comment: Create a reproducible test page